# How to launch a roslaunch in Qt with a terminal (GUI)?

Tags: roslaunch, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a GUI with Qt and now I want to link the GUI with my ROS program by launching the launch file.
To launch my launch file I have found a solution : in my GUI (Qt C++) open a terminal and execute my roslaunch. But it's not as easy as it seems...

I have found 2 possible solutions in Qt:

- stdlib.h : system("gnome-terminal -e roslaunch my_package file.launch");

I get this error : (gnome-terminal:386): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'host' from schema 'org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.

It seems that the spaces in "roslaunch my_package file.launch" don't work.

- QProcess builder;

  builder.start("gnome-terminal", QStringList() << "roslaunch my_package file.launch");

In these two cases, a terminal opens but nothing append...
I have tried with a simple exemple (mkdir file) and the command works, It seems that the roslaunch is not recognized as a command.

Do you have a solution ? Any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209090/how-to-launch-a-roslaunch-in-qt-with-a-terminal-(gui)-?/) by [waffaw69](https://answers.ros.org/users/22409/waffaw69/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2017-04-10**:
Roslaunch provides Python API ([Example](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage)). One possible solution is to call roslaunch Python API from cpp([call Python from cpp](https://www.coveros.com/calling-python-code-from-c/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered a similar behaviour, and to me the reason was that I had not loaded the ros environment parameters. That is what is loaded through "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash".

You could add it to your command, for QProcess this become:

```
builder.start("gnome-terminal", QStringList() << "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash; roslaunch my_package file.launch");
```

I hope you had already solved your problem, but the same solution could be helpful for others.

---

Originally posted by [basti35](https://answers.ros.org/users/27670/basti35/) with karma: 16 on 2016-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nicky0201](https://answers.ros.org/users/28591/nicky0201/) on 2016-11-22**:
I tried this and it seems that it only opens the terminal but not run the roslaunch command...
is there a way to do it?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-04-10**:
You probably want to add `bash -c` at the front of the command and put the rest of the command as an argument to bash.

**Comment by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on 2017-09-28**:
Hi! i try both gnome-terminal comand and bash -c and both didnt work. Is it because i need to configure my cmake file or someting like that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try
system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c " roslaunch xxx xxx; bash"");

---

Originally posted by [dlc](https://answers.ros.org/users/34832/dlc/) with karma: 21 on 2018-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2